# Getting HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long. - Microsoft.Azure.Documents.DocumentClientException

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have an Azure CosmosDb, I am trying to access it from the application using Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core. It was working okay and then it started throwing/getting:

> HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.

I believe it has nothing do with code, but the have attached the code I use.

I have tried clearing cookies and increasing CosmosDb throughput.

```
using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri(DocumentsDatabaseBaseUrl), AuthKey))
        {
            var parameters = new SqlParameterCollection {new SqlParameter("test", testvalue)};

            var querySpec = new SqlQuerySpec
            {
                Parameters = parameters,
                QueryText = $"query"
            };

            using (var queryable = client.CreateDocumentQuery<T>(
                this.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(),
                querySpec,
                new FeedOptions {MaxItemCount = 1, EnableCrossPartitionQuery = true}).AsDocumentQuery())
            {
                while (queryable.HasMoreResults)
                {
                    foreach (var row in await queryable.ExecuteNextAsync<T>())
                    {
                        return (true, row);
                    }
                }
            }
            return (false, default(T));
        }
```

Comment: and the response I receive at the moment is <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN""http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<HTML>
 <HEAD>
  <TITLE>Bad Request</TITLE>
  <META HTTP-EQUIV="Content-Type" Content="text/html; charset=us-ascii">
  </HEAD>
  <BODY>
   <h2>Bad Request - Request Too Long</h2>
   <hr>
    <p>HTTP Error 400. The size of the request headers is too long.</p>
   </BODY>
  </HTML>
, Request URI: /dbs/test/colls/test1/docs, RequestStats: , SDK: Windows/6.1.7601 documentdb-netcore-sdk/2.4.0

Comment: Which SDK version? Are you using Gateway or Direct mode?